# can't stop mp3 file from playing

Tags: android

I am new to android programming. I have an mp3 file playing, but won't stop playing when back button is pressed to exit program. I have the MediaPlayer in global, shouldn't it be picked up in back key code? Any help appreciated.

```
public class JabberWockyActivity extends Activity {
WebView myWebView;
Button button1;
Button button2;
MediaPlayer mpAudio;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jabber_wocky);

    mpAudio=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yah3);
    mpAudio.start();
    mpAudio.setLooping(true);       

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.jabberwocky.com/carroll/jabber/jabberwocky.html");




    button1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                    .parse("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });


    button2 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                .parse("http://goodvibeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/jabberwocky2.jpg"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
});
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.jabber_wocky, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mpAudio.stop();
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;

    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Comment: it should, did u ensure that your onKeyDown is actually called? since it depends on the webviews canGoBack result if it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call release() in OnDestroy() method.

```
 @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
     super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
     }
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. This is great site and am enjoying android java. Thanks again.

Comment: I only have a rating of 8. I need 15 to vote up. I'm a real newbie.